# How can I get Typeahead.js to autocomplete or select using one field of an object and not all of it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, typeahead.js

I currently have this code to set up Typeahead:

```
var people = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace("personName"),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    local: generateCastDb()
});

$('#app-container .search-box').typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 1
},
{
    name: 'people',
    source: people,
    templates: {
        suggestion: function (data) {
            return '<p>' + data["personName"] + '</p>';
        }
    }
});
```

`generateCastDb` returns an array of objects similar to this:

```
{personId: "293", personName: "Roger Pratt", appearances: [{mediaId: "11834", mediaType: "movie", characterName: "Man Living in Barrel"}]}
```

As you can see, I am using this `personName` field for Typeahead's autocomplete suggestions. The dropdown appears perfectly well, but when I select one of the options (using arrow keys *or* mouse), the entire object appears in the input box instead of just the `personName` value.

How can I make the search box update using just that one field instead of the entire object? I have tried using `jQuery.val()` to set it when the `typeahead:selected` event fires, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `displayKey` attribute

```
$('#app-container .search-box').typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 1
  }, {
    name: 'people',
    source: people,
    displayKey: 'personName', // <---- this noe
    templates: {
      suggestion: function(data) {
        return '<p>' + data["personName"] + '</p>';
      }
    }
  });
});
```

displayKey can also be replaced by display like this

```
display: function(item){
    return item.personName;
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I Googled for "autocomplete", "selection" and other things. I had no idea it was called display.